# C# Using regex to get multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex

```
var userVersionHTML = "2448hello2448welcome2448";
Regex regex = new Regex("2448(.*?)2448");
var v = regex.Match(userVersionHTML);
versionNumberStatus.Text = v.Groups[1].ToString();
usernameStatus.Text = v.Groups[2].ToString();
```

The goal is to get `versionNumberStatus.Text` to display 'hello' and for `usernameStatus.Text` to display 'welcome'.

The issue is that nothing appears for the `usernameStatus.Text`. Any ideas?

Comment: You only have 1 capturing group here, in `"2448(.*?)2448"` pattern so you cannot access `.Groups[2]`. Split with `2448`. Or use the `2448(.*?)2448(.*?)2448` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're the best

Comment: I posted an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have *one* capturing group here, in `"2448(.*?)2448"` pattern so you cannot access `.Groups[2]`.

A solution is to either split with `2448` or use the `2448(.*?)2448(.*?)2448` pattern.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=2448(.*%3f)2448(.*%3f)2448&i=2448hello2448welcome2448).

Or this [C# code:](https://ideone.com/EWMDcZ)

```
var userVersionHTML = "2448hello2448welcome2448";
var chunks = userVersionHTML.Split(new[] {"2448"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
var versionNumberStatus = chunks[0];
var usernameStatus = chunks[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to use `Matches()` with a regex like this:

```
var userVersionHTML = "2448hello2448welcome2448";

Regex regex = new Regex("(2448)?(.*?)2448");
var v = regex.Matches(userVersionHTML);

versionNumberStatus.Text = v[0].Groups[2].ToString();
usernameStatus.Text = v[1].Groups[2].ToString();
```

Comment: much more generic and complete than accepted answer